# Implementing a factorisation method in Haskell

Tags: haskell, factorization

I am doing [question 266](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=266) at Project Euler and after a bit of searching, found [this method](http://www.gmathacks.com/gmat-math/number-of-factors-of-a-large-integer.html) of quickly finding the factors of a number. What you do is find all the permutations of the prime factors of a number: these are its factors.

I already have a module to find the prime power factors of a number, eg:

```
Main> primePowerFactors 196
[(2,2),(7,2)]
```

This is basically showing that: `2^2 * 7^2 == 196`. From here I want to find all the permutations of those powers,  to give the factors of 196 thusly:

- (2^0)(7^0) = 1
- (2^1)(7^0) = 2
- (2^2)(7^0) = 4
- (2^0)(7^1) = 7
- (2^1)(7^1) = 14
- (2^2)(7^1) = 28
- (2^0)(7^2) = 49
- (2^1)(7^2) = 98

I came up with the following:

```
factors n = [a|a<-map facs (primePowerFactors n), y <- [0..(snd $ last $ primePowerFactors n)]]
 where 
  facs (x,y) = (x,y)   
rSq n = toInteger $ round $ sqrt (fromInteger n)    
psr n = last $ dropWhile (<= rSq n) $ factors n
p = foldl' (*) 1 $ takeWhile (< 190) primes
answer = (psr p) `mod` (10^16)
```

But my problem is that `factors` doesn't work properly. I want it to permute through all the possible values of the exponent for each prime factor and then find the product to give the factor.  How can it be modified to return the just the factors of *n*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some code golf i wrote a nice power set function that is pretty simple.

```
powerSet [] = []
powerSet (x:xs) = xs : map (x:) (powerSet xs) ++ (powerSet xs)
```

A deficiency of this algorithm is that it doesn't include the original set, however that is perfect for you since it doesn't look like you want it.

combine this with a way to convert your `primePowerFactors n` into a list of ints, lets say

```
ppfToList = concatMap (\(x,y)->replicate y x)
```

using these helpers, a list of factors from a number n is generated with

```
factors n = nub . map product . powerSet . ppfToList . primePowerFactors $ n
-- will be out of order, you can add a call to `sort` to fix that
```

This sort of algorithm is probably a bit harder to express in terms of a list comprehension.

Comment: When you want the factors of a very large number, it becomes important that the factors of the number are produced in order, otherwise using sort will require it to store EVERY SINGLE factor in memory before sorting and then giving me my number. Since we know there are 2^42 factors for p, the one we want should be at index 2^42 -1 in the sorted list of factors.

Comment: actually you don't need to sort according to the spec.  you need to find the maximum that is below a certain threshold.  that is just `maximum . filter (/= threshold)`, which is linear with an optimised constant overhead (should be anyway).

Comment: sorry `maximum . filter (<= threshold)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `facs` is the identity function:

```
facs (x,y) = (x,y)
```

The `y` is bound in the pattern match on the left hand side while you probably intended it to be the `y` from the list comprehension. Variable names bound in a list comprehension are local to that comprehension and can not be used in a different scope like the `where` clause.

Also, the `y` in the list comprehension is only computed from the last factors exponent:

```
y <- [0..(snd $ last $ primePowerFactors n)]
```

For each factor it's own exponent should be considered, not just always the exponent of the last factor.

A more fundamental problem is, that the return type of the `factors` function doesn't seem to match it's intention:

```
*Euler> :t factors
factors :: Integer -> [(Integer, Int)]
```

This returns a list of powers of prime factors while it should produce a list of these constructs, like this:

```
[
   [(2,0), (7,0)],
   [(2,1), (7,0)],
   [(2,2), (7,0)],
   [(2,0), (7,1)],
   [(2,1), (7,1)],
   ...
]
```

The prime factorization of all possible factors is needed, but the function seems to return just one prime factorization.

Comment: Oh, I think that was a mistake, it should be:
`facs (x,y) = (x^y)` so that `factors` returns a list of Integers

Comment: With the changed `facs` you never generate something like `2^1*7^1`, but only factors that are the power of one prime. The algorithms needs to be changed to also produce combinations of different prime factors.