# implementing a per-digit counter using the list monad

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

So, I was looking at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855561/implementing-a-factorisation-method-in-haskell), and built a rather ugly solution for the problem.  While trying to clean it up, I started investigating list comprehensions and the list monad.  What I decided to do was to implement a per-digit counter using the list monad.  Given an input sequence of digits, `[1, 2]`, I wanted to generate an output sequence that looked something like:

```
[ [ 0, 0],
  [ 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 2 ],
  [ 1, 0 ],
  [ 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 2 ] ]
```

That is, I'd iterate over all possible values of all elements in the list in that range.

The haskell.org [list monad documentation](http://www.haskell.org/all_about_monads/html/listmonad.html) says:

> The bound function is applied to all possible values in the input list and the resulting lists are concatenated to produce a list of all possible results.

Great!  Looks perfect...  Here's the code I wrote to produce the solution:

```
count :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
count [] = []
count (x:xs) =
  -- get all possible sequences for the remaining digits
  let
    remDigits :: [[Integer]]
    remDigits = count xs
  in
  -- pull out a possible sequence for the remaining digits
  do nextDigits <- remDigits
     -- pull out all possible values for the current digit
     y <- [0..x]
     -- record that "current digit" : "remaining digits" is
     -- a valid output.
     return (y:nextDigits)
```

But calling `count` with anything produces the empty list, and I don't know why.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you simply change your base case to `count [] = [[]]`, this code works.

Comment: Actually, this was precisely the answer I was looking for...  I had figured out that my problem was that, in the base case, there were no solutions in the list monad, so there was nothing to build out from.  CBFraser's answer below addressed that, but your solution is closer to what I had in mind originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need a base case for the singleton list as an argument. Try this:

```
count :: [Integer] -> [[Integer]]
count [] = []
count [n] = map (\x -> [x]) [0..n]
count (x:xs) =
     do y <- [0..x]
        nextDigits <- count xs
        return (y:nextDigits)

 main = do
   print $ count [1]
   print $ count [1,2]
```

Comment: Produces a different result than the OP has specified!

Comment: The remaining bug has to do with the order in which I was using the monads.  I should have had y <- [0..x] on the outside, and nextDigits <- count xs on the inside.

Answer (score 8):

```
count = sequence . map (enumFromTo 0)
```

Yes, it's really as simple as that.  Give it a try :)

Answer (score 8):

even shorter

```
count = mapM (enumFromTo 0)
```

Comment: D'oh, not sure how I missed the mechanical translation of `sequence+map` to `mapM`, but +1 for the obvious improvement :D

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, you can also express the logic as a list comprehension, which is probably the best way to use the list monad for simple functions:

```
count (x:xs) = [ (y:ys) | y <- [0..x], ys <- count xs ]
```